# How to dynamically prepare sql statement which also dynamically include the fields name

Tags: php, mysql

How to prepare fields name dynamically in sql statement.

Here is my query but it return 500 error. Im guessing this is because I'm preparing names dynamically.

Is there any way to prepare fields name dynamically in sql statement.

```
if (!($update_stmt = $mysqli_scs->prepare("UPDATE `signs_sgn` SET ? = ? , ?=? WHERE (`signcode_sgn`= ?) LIMIT 1;"))) {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli_scs->errno . ") " . $mysqli_scs->error;
            }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: identifiers != strings. You can't prep a query with column/identifier placeholders. You will have to build that part of the query without placeholders.

Comment: You cannot add column names as place holder. You have to concate strings here

Comment: So what would be best alternative i should do which has no security risks.

Comment: The very best alternative is to not accept column names as user input.